# New computer running arch linux gets weirdly loud

Tags: arch-linux, memory, disk-usage, performance, cpu-usage

I have a relatively new computer and I just installed Arch linux. From the moment I start the computer, it starts with a loud noise that is very similiar to a computer running on 100% of the CPU. From what I could gather, there is no reason for that because my CPU usage, memory usage and disk IO are very low:

[image: Memory & CPU usage]

[image: Disk IO - iotop]

Any ideas what might be causing this anomaly?

PS.: I have a no-break installed and the room the computer is in is not hot at all.

EDIT 1:

@terdon
[image: powersave]

@Bib
[image: powertop]

EDIT 2:

```
Operating System: Arch Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.23.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.90.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.15.15-1-lts (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 20 × Intel® Core™ i9-10900K CPU @ 3.70GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630
```

Motherboard:

```
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
TUF GAMING Z490-PLUS
Rev 1.xx
```

HDD:

```
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST2000DM008-2FR102
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jan 22 15:07:23 2022 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

EDIT 3:

lm_sensors (sensors):

```
acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8 C  (crit = +119.0 C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +32.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 0:        +28.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 1:        +30.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 2:        +29.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 3:        +28.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 4:        +29.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 5:        +26.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 6:        +31.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 7:        +28.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 8:        +34.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 9:        +28.0 C  (high = +82.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
```

FAN Profile:

```
CPU Fan: 827 RPM
CHA1 Fan: N/A
CHA2 Fan: N/A
CHA3 Fan: N/A
CPU Opt Fan: N/A
AIO Pump: 2280 RPM
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor | sort | uniq`. Also read https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling. Finally, also add your CPU temperature when this is happening, confirm that it is indeed the CPU fanm making the noise, and add the fan's RPM (all of this should be available through [`lm-sensors`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lm_sensors)).

Comment: Use `top` or `powertop` rather than `iotop` which in this instance is rather pointless.

Comment: @terdon the info you requested is under EDIT 1

Comment: @Bib the info you requested is under EDIT 1

Comment: Is that the fan that is loud? Maybe some bios tweaks 'cool and quiet' stuff like that?

Comment: Thanks, but as a general rule, please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: 1) The CPU governor alone **cannot** make the CPU fan run at full speed. 2) **Cool and quiet** is a 20 yo feature not present in current AMD systems. 3) I don't understand why there's no `top` output but `iotop` output is given. IO rarely can cause any power management issues. 4) The type of computer is not specified, e.g. a laptop can easily get loud if the GPU is busy. 5) No HW info is given as well. Overall this is quite a sad guessing game.

Comment: @yarl I just changed Q Fan control to PWN and set all the fans to `silent` and it helped a little bit. Thanks. But its still too loud for a computer that is basically idling.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have edited and added info about the system and the hardware. It's not a game, I'm just not an expert like you are, I'm doing my best. All you need to do is ask. No need to be testy.

Comment: @terdon I had forgoten to add the last bit of info you requested so I added it at EDIT 3.

Comment: Your temps are perfectly fine and indicative of a very low CPU use, which fan produces the most noise? As far as I can see you've got AIO.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not sure which fan makes the more noise. It seems to be the CPU. Also, I have a GeForce graphics card which is unloaded because I'm passing through to a virtual machine. It could also be coming from it. But I cant get any info on it because it's not loaded.

Comment: Could be an incorrectly/aggressively configured fan curve in your UEFI/BIOS. Nothing that you've shown so far could indicate that it's because of Linux. Would be great if you ran Windows and verified the system's working properly and is not affected. Lastly some NVIDIA GPUs at least in the past used to run at full fan speed until the drivers were loaded. This could be the case considering you're saying that *"it's unloaded"*.

Comment: Alright I was afraid of that. I'll do that at some point. Thanks though.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Oh... I've seen that we can configure fan speed for nvidia cards but as far as I've tested they all come back with an error saying that it's unloaded. I'll try to load it, change it and then return to the original config.

Comment: Again, it's not just the GPU that has a fan curve, your CPU also has one and it's configured via UEFI.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yeah I've seen it in the BIOS, I've set it to silent(which changed the curve) and under PWN Mode along with all the other fans that were available there and I listed them under FAN Profile.

Comment: Since you have a builtin GPU, can you run your system without an NVIDIA GPU and check if you still have the noise? We still seemingly haven't identified the source of it. Since you're physically near the device I presume, can you just move your head around and maybe see what's loud in the system? Should be doable I guess.